# Emitting event in Node.js

Tags: node.js, eventemitter

I'm trying to teach myself both javascript and nodejs at the same time here and have not been able to get custom event emitting working. I am not receiving any errors, just not seeing the event being emitted. Is someone able to point out my (likely obvious) logical error?

I have a class declared in a separate module:

```
var util = require( 'util' ),
events = require( 'events' );


function logger(){
    var logpath, initialised, logstream;
    events.EventEmitter.call(this);
}
util.inherits(logger, events.EventEmitter);

logger.prototype.init = function(){
    this.emit( 'initialised' );
}

exports.logger = logger;
```

And then a main file:

```
var logger = require( "./logManager" ).logger;

var myLogger = new logger;

myLogger.init();

myLogger.on( 'initialised' ){
     console.log( "IT'S ALIVE!" );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you have a syntax error in your main file. When you attach an event handler, that event handler is always a `function`, and the signature is `on(eventName, eventHandler)`, so you need:

```
myLogger.on('initialised', function() {
    console.log("IT'S ALIVE!");
});
```

Also, you have to attach the event handler *before* you call `init`, or you will miss the event, so in full:

```
var logger = require( "./logManager" ).logger;

var myLogger = new logger;

myLogger.on('initialised', function() {
    console.log("IT'S ALIVE!");
});

myLogger.init();
```

Comment: Argh! The syntax error was just when I coppied the code into this question, my real problem was not setting the event handler before the event was emitted... Such a simple problem I can't believe I missed that.

Thank you very much for help!