# How to return a function from callback?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

If I have the following code:

```
var content;
var f = fs.readFile('./index.html', function read(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    content = data;
    return console.log(content);
});

f();
```

I got the following:

```
f();
^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

How can I do to return a function, which is not undefined?

My real issue, in a bigger context is the following https://gist.github.com/jrm2k6/5962230

Comment: You don't, you need to perform the actions _inside_ the readFile callback - or wrap it in a function that accepts a callback itself. See [this similar post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call/16825593#16825593) on how to return from an AJAX call.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Well, `f` *could* be a function. However, `fs.readFile()` does not return one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't *usefully* `return` from within the callback to your code.

1. Using `return` inside the callback doesn't return a value to your code. `fs.readFile()` calls the callback itself so the `return` value is given to it. For your code to receive it, `fs.readFile()` would have to `return` the value it got from the callback, which it doesn't.
2. And, since `fs.readFile()` is asynchronous, it actually can't. Your code spans 2 different points in time:

   1. "Present"

      ```
      var content;
      var f = fs.readFile('./index.html', /* ... */);

      f();
      ```
   2. "Future"

      ```
      /* ... */
      function read(err, data) {
          if (err) {
              throw err;
          }
          content = data;
          return console.log(content);
      }
      /* ... */
      ```

You simply can't use a value from the "*Future*" in the "*Present*" -- or, at that point, the "*Past*."

This all generally leads to continuing the `callback` pattern rather than using `return`. Taking your ["*real*" code](https://gist.github.com/jrm2k6/5962230):

```
var cheerioURLContent = function (url, callback) {
    rest.get(url).on("complete", function (result) {
        callback(cheerio.load(result));
    });
};

cheerioURLContent('./index.html', function (t) {
    console.log(t);
});
```

Comment: Ok, and what if I need to assign this function cheerioURLContent to a variable, which has to be a function? I have to delay this assignment right?

Comment: @JeremyD The issue is in trying to set `var t = cheerio.load(result);` before there's actually a `result`. Just as `fs.readFile()` couldn't `return` a value from the callback, neither can `cheerioURLContent` nor `rest.get()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign event handlers for custom events and trigger (emit) the events from within the callback. It's a bit hard to get your head around at first, but pretty elegant.

See [Emitting event in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9479765/emitting-event-in-node-js) for an example.